# String to char array with space complexity O(1)

Tags: java, string, char

is there any way to get char[] from a String in java and has space complexity = O(1)?

I try with toCharArray but the space complexity = O(n)

Comment: You mean without copying the string? Not without dangerous reflection.

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: I have a homework: with a String input, reverse this String by word with complexity is O(1). Ex: Input: I am superman -> output: superman am I. I solved it by swap char in this String but I have problem when get char[] from this String for swapping.  I consider about StringBuilder but space complexity not O(1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one possible way of doing this, but it is **NOT AT ALL RECOMMENDED**. You can use Java Reflection API to get the private field `value` from the string class which is thy type `char[]` and then get that field's value for an object. You can do so by using the following code:

```
Field valueField = String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
field.setAccessible(true);

String str = "This is my String";
char[] charArr = (char[]) valueField.get(str);
```

Changing the value of the char array can mess up things really fast and you will see its effect throughout the system as Java maintains a pool of strings and can intern them as requested.

Answer (score 2):

Because Strings are immutable in Java, the backing character array is never exposed (there would be no way to prevent you from modifying its contents). Older versions of Java also support storing ASCII strings in a compressed way, so there isn't even a guarantee String is backed by characters.

You *can* do this with array-backed CharBuffers. CharBuffer, like String, even implements CharSequence, so it will be compatible with some APIs (like Pattern.matcher).